# How do I create a water ripple (distorted) effect on text?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, typography, photoshop-effects, illustrator-effects

How would I create text with this type of effect in either Photoshop or Illustrator?[image]

[image: Example - 1]

Comment: Illustrator: Same basic method as here: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/98489/3270

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're after a more watery effect then use a displacement map.

Original text:

[image]

Post effect:

[image]

This is done very easily.

1. Download an image of flowing water.
2. Convert the image to greyscale by going 'Image' - 'Mode' and 'GreyScale'.
3. Save the grey image as psd.
4. In a new psd file, write your text.
5. Then go 'Filter' - 'Distort' - 'Displace' play around with the numbers to get your ripple just right, then chose the grey image psd.

Voila.

Comment: Thank you! Took some trial and error, but using this technique I eventually got the visual I desired with my typography.

Comment: Great, I'm glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

An easy way for something similar will be to rasterize the text layer and then transforming it. Rasterizing text layer can be done by right clicking on the layer and selecting `rasterize layer`. This will make the text layer behave like normal image layers and it can be transformed in a variety of way using `warp,distort` options. For transformation shortcut is `ctrl+t` and then right click on the active selection to change transformation mode. Play with it.

Note : rasterizing text layer will remove text editing capability. So it is important to finalize the text before starting transformation.
Will try to add a pictorial guide later.